# What is the difference between Boolean logic and propositional logic?

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

As far as I can see, they only employ different symbols but they operate in the same way. Am I missing something?

I wanted to write "Boolean logic" in the tag box but a message came up saying that if I wanted to write Boolean logic I should better write propositional logic. Doesn't this confirm my suspicions?

Comment: Very similar; see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Propositional_logic).  Boolean algebra is a form of algebra, with 0's and 1's.

Comment: You can see also [The Mathematics of Boolean Algebra](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boolalg-math/) and [The Algebra of Logic Tradition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/algebra-logic-tradition/).

Comment: Thank you for the links, but I would like straight answers. I understand that  most if not all concepts in Boolean logic can be "translated" in propositional logic, but this does nothing but to ask the question what is the difference between Boolean logic and propositional logic? Surely, if all concepts in Boolean logic can be found in propositional logic, does this not mean that they are the same?

Comment: Boolean algebra is the study of an algebraic structure. The boolena algebra of $0$ and $1$ is a model of *classical* propositional calculus.

Comment: "Boolean algebra is the study of an algebraic structure." Of any algebraic structure? Or of a particular type of algebraic structure? Is there a Boolean algebra that is not of 0 and 1 (bivalent)?
So is the difference between Boolean logic and propositional logic only syntactical?

Comment: In my comment i've been sloppy ... "The theory of *Boolean algebras* is the study of a family of algebraic structures, called "boolean algebras"".

Comment: You can see some textbook on Boolean algebra : Roman Sikorski, [Boolean algebras](https://books.google.it/books?id=3RudMQEACAAJ) (3rd ed 1969) or Steven Givant & Paul Halmos, [Introduction to Boolean algebras](https://books.google.it/books?id=ORILyf8sF2sC&printsec=frontcover) (2009).

Comment: Thank you for the information and the references, Mauro.

Comment: @JFarobek See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Propositional_logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can see :

- J.Donald Monk, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=iRCbJQMSn2EC) (1976), **Ch.9 Boolean algebra**, page 141-on :

> In this chapter we give a brief introduction to the theory of Boolean algebras. As we shall see, these are *algebraic structures which stand in an intimate relationship to* [classical] *sentential logics* [emphasis added]. They will also form a source for some of the applications of logic which we shall give later.

See page 158 :

> [regarding] the correspondence between Boolean algebras and sentential logics [...] We shall see that there is a full correspondence between these two kinds of mathematical objects.

Finally, see page 160 :

> the following theorem, which is another kind of completeness theorem for Boolean algebras. [...] Hence we may say that the theories of Boolean algebras and of sentential logics are equivalent, in some sense.

---

You can see also :

- J.L. Bell & A.B. Slomson, [Models and Ultraproducts: An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=VWFL8uUa6iYC&pg=PA11) (1969 - Dover reprint), page 11 :

> a *Boolean algebra* is a complemented [distributive lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice) with at least two elements.

Page 40 :

> we impose the structure of a boolean algebra on the set $F$ of formulas of [*sentential calculus*] $SC$ [...] by first defining the relation $\equiv$ on $F$ by :
>
> > $$\phi \equiv \psi \ \text {iff} \ \vdash \phi \to \psi \ \text {and} \ \vdash \psi \to \phi.$$
>
> If $\phi$ is a formula in $F$, we let $|\phi|$ the equivalence class under the relation $\equiv$ to which it belongs. Thus
>
> > $$|\phi| = \{ \psi \in F : \phi \equiv \psi \}.$$
>
> We let
>
> > $$F/\equiv = \{ |\phi| : \phi \in F \}.$$
>
> Now we can define the relation $\le$ on $F/\equiv$ by
>
> > $$|\phi| \le |\psi| \ \text {iff} \ \vdash \phi \to \psi.$$

Thus, we have that :

> $\mathcal A = \langle F/\equiv \le \rangle$ *is a complemented distriutive lattice, that is a Boolean algebra*.

Comment: Perhaps you should also mention that only *classical* propositional logic is "Boolean", and propositional logic also comes in such non-Boolean flavors as many-valued ("moolean"), intuitionistic,  and "relevant".

Comment: Thank you Mauro and Bof! "Perhaps you should also mention that only classical propositional logic is "Boolean", and propositional logic also comes in such non-Boolean flavors." Yes, I was missing that detail!